# Receive jQuery ajax posted value in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form where the user inputs data and a table that shows all the rows in the database. Now when the user clicks an "edit"-link next to one of the rows I want to post the ID to the PHP file and load the data in the row into the form.

This is how I post the ID (and it works)

```
jQuery('a.edit').on('mousedown', function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location,
        data: {id: id}
    });
})
```

This is how I tried to receive the posted ID (doesn't work)

```
if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    load_data($id);
}
```

I guess I need to refresh the page? How can I do that? Can I also just refresh the form?

**EDIT:** I still think it's a reload/refresh issue. The value is being posted, but my PHP doesn't recognize because it is not reloaded. I've seen people doing this with jQuery instead of reloading the whole page, but I fail to recreate this. Maybe it is also worth mentioning that theses files are part of a Wordpress Plugin..

So this is the whole code (my plugin is called "spielerportraits")

spielerportraits-admin.php

```
<?php 
function print_data(){
    global $wpdb;
    $datatable = $wpdb->get_results( 
        'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'spielerportraits' ); 
?>

<table id="spieler-output">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Geb.datum</td>
    </tr>

<?php foreach( $datatable as $data ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->gebdatum; ?></td>
        <td><a href="" class="edit" data-title="<?php echo $data->id;?>">bearbeiten</a></td> // The edit-link for jQuery
    </tr>

<?php }
?>
    </table>
<?php
} 

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $loaddata = $wpdb->get_row( 
        'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'spielerportraits WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'] ); 
}
?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="spieler-form" action="" method="post">
    <table id="spieler-input">
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if( isset($loaddata) ){echo $loaddata->name;}?>" size="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Geburtsdatum: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="gebdatum" value="<?php if( isset($loaddata) ){echo $loaddata->gebdatum;}?>" size="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Hinzufügen" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    print_data();
?>
```

The JS

```
jQuery('a.edit').on('mousedown', function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location,
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data['id']); // This does show, but gives me 'undefined'
        }
    });
});
```

And this is how the plugin is initialised in Wordpress (spielerportraits.php):

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'spielerportraits_style' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'spielerportraits_custom_menu_page');

function spielerportraits_custom_menu_page() {
   $page = add_menu_page( 'Spielerportraits', 'Spielerportraits', 'manage_options', 'spielerportraits/spielerportraits-admin.php', '', '' ), 33 );
}

function spielerportraits_style() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'spielerportraits-admin-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__) );

}

global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = "1.0";

function jal_install() {
   global $wpdb;
   global $jal_db_version;

   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'spielerportraits';

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        gebdatum date',
        PRIMARY KEY id (id)
    );";

    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( "jal_db_version", $jal_db_version );
    }
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install' );

?>
```

Comment: You should specify a callback for ajax-request.

Comment: Check the console, are you sure the request is actually going through?

Comment: What makes you think the jquery code works? you may be getting the alert, that doesn't mean the ajax call is working

Comment: I did an alert on success (worked) and I can see the value being posted to the corret PHP file in Firebug

Comment: the request is heading to nowhere ( 'document.location' ), what is the value of it?

Comment: document.location is the path to the document that the click came from. I checked it and it's the correct path.

Comment: An ajax call doesn't require a page refresh, please post the exact code of your plugin, we need: JS and PHP action being called from ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kind of a reload issue. This is what I did to make it work:

```
jQuery('a.edit').on('mousedown', function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    alert(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location,
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
            newDoc.write(data);
            newDoc.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of just replacing parts of the document, this method gives you page history, which is very helpful for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an ajax call might look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl, // for example a PHP file that will process the request
  data:{
    mykey: myvalue
  },
  success: function( data ){
    console.log( data );
  } 
});
```

and the PHP file might look like this:

```
$mykey = isset( $_GET['mykey'] ) ? $_GET['mykey'] : false;

if( $mykey ){
  //Do whatever you like with this, but you need to print out something: a return value
  echo $mykey
}
```

I think you need to `echo` the value returned by `load_data($id);`, if this value is an array i suggest you :

```
echo json_encode( load_data($id) );
```

Hope it helps! let me know if you get stuck

Answer (score -1):

Need to inform type of request method:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
...
```

Comment: GET method is default, it's not necessary to declare it

Answer (score -2):

change `$_GET` to `$_POST` as you are posting data

Comment: If `method` parameter is not passed to `$.ajax` it is considered to be `GET`